# How to return a value from a method which have call back?

Tags: java, android

I want to get the detail of the user from the facebook sdk. I am using this method now i want to return the id of the user, i don't know how to do it please help.

```
private String getUserId() 
{
    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), 
                                  new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
              {
                   @Override
                   public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                   {
                        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                        GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();

                        if(graphObject != null) 
                        {
                            if(error == null) 
                            {
                                Preferences.saveUserInfo(user.getId(),
                                                         FetchGroups.this);
                                Preferences.saveUserName(user.getName(),
                                                         FetchGroups.this);

                                return user.getId();
                            }
                         }
                    }
              });
}
```

This is giving me error the onCompletd method have return type void. Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a suggestion, can you not extract the ID in onPostExecute()from the AsyncTask() ?

Comment: I am not using AsyncTask() here.

Comment: create listener for it, do you know how to do it?

Comment: @deadfish you mean i will have to make a interface for this? to create a listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No,you cannot return like that.Make a global variable and assign it and use it later.

```
public class SomeClass  {
 String useid;
```

--

```
     Request.executeMeRequestAsync(Session.getActiveSession(), new Request.GraphUserCallback() {

                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                    GraphObject graphObject = response.getGraphObject();
                    if(graphObject != null) {
                        if(error == null) {
                            Preferences.saveUserInfo(user.getId(), FetchGroups.this);
                            Preferences.saveUserName(user.getName(), FetchGroups.this);
                             userid = user.getId();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: i am already doing this, but i don't want to do this, i have to return. Is not there any other option for doing this?

Comment: How can you return a variable from an anonymous inner class method ?*IMHO* No,And that too that method return type is Void ,if you see.

Answer (score 0):

instead make id global and access it throughout the activity.